# Почему не запускается скрипт бота дискорд?

Tags: python, discord.py

Когда я запускаю бота, он на секунду появляется, и сразу исчезает.
В чем проблема? Почему он выключается, он не пишет.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready(): #пишем сообщение при запуске
    Channel = client.get_channel('709320705476526111') #ищем айди канала
    Text= "Нажми на реакцию, чтобы получить роль @Программист" #текст для сообщения
    Moji = await client.send_message(Channel, Text) #отправить сообщение
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='') #отправка сообщения и добавление реакции (вроде)
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('709320705476526111') 
    if reaction.message.channel.id==Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Программист")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
client.run=('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете бота?

Comment: Открываю скрипт с ботом. А что?

Comment: Запустите через консоль и покажите вывод

Comment: https://prnt.sc/semp2o вот